# find_element in dataframe in R

Tags: r, function

I am new to R. I wanted to define a R function, find_element, that takes as its inputs a list and a value of any type, and returns the value of the matched element in the input list that matches the value. thanks for your help

```
find_element <- function(arr, val){
 count = 0
  for(i in arr){
  if (i == val){
    print(count)
 } else 
   count = count + 1
   print ("No Match")
}
}
```

e.g.

```
arr <- 1:10
find_element(arr, 10)
# 10
find_element(arr, 12)
# NULL
```

Comment: do you mean `which()`? i.e. `which(arr == 10)`

Comment: well i want to  have function so i should learn making function instead using direct built in function thanks for your answer. i just want the above code so i can get the answer i am looking for

Comment: Thanks uwe  However, when i ran the code it give me strange out could pls point out what i should change to get required out mentioned. thanks find_element(a, 1)
[1] 0
[1] "No Match"
[1] "No Match"
[1] "No Match"
[1] "No Match"
[1] "No Match"
[1] "No Match"
[1] "No Match"
[1] "No Match"
[1] "No Match"

Comment: Thanks I guess its not doing what i am trying to achieve. It gives me following results > arr <- 1:10
> find_element(arr, 10)
[1] 9
> find_element(arr, 12)
[1] "No Match"
>

Answer (score 1):

Just for educational purposes, please, try (*although this is **not** recommended practice in R!*):

```
find_element <- function(arr, val) {
  count = 1
  for (i in arr) {
    if (i == val) {
      return(count)
    } else
      count = count + 1
  }
  return("No Match")
}
```

This will yield

```
arr <- 1:10
find_element(arr, 10)
#[1] 10
find_element(arr, 12)
#[1] "No Match"
```

Please, note

1. In R, elements of vectors, etc are numbered starting with `1`
2. You  have to use `return` instead of `print` to indicate the return value of a function (well, I know there's a short cut - but it's for the purpose of education, here)
3. The final `return` must come after the for loop.

### Built-in function

Also for educational purposes, please, note that *Sotos* already has shown the *R way* in his comment:

```
which(arr == 10)
#[1] 10
which(arr == 12)
#integer(0)
```

In R, it's almost always better to use the well-documented built-in functions or those from packages. And, yes, try to avoid `for` loops in R.

### Learnig R online

As pointed out in the (now deleted) answer of *engAnt* there are several ressources to learn R. https://www.rstudio.com/online-learning/#R lists a number of resources.